# SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: pandas, numpy

## the issue

1. I have read all possible solutions to get rid of the warning  *"SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"*

but NOTHING worked, I can't get rid of the error message.

Many thank in advance for the time you will invest help me and certainly more people

## which tools do I use

I am using kaggle to run a notebook, the configuration is straightfoward, I didn't load any library

## the goal

I want to round a column and create a new one with the result

## the data

```
id;    city.coord.lon; city.coord.lat 
12957; 4.32664;        51.219791    
12958; 3.33848;        50.812679 
12959; 3.81052;        50.869560
```

## how is df_weather_in_cities created?

```py
    # load the history city list
    with open(history_city_list_path) as f: 
        d = json.load(f) 

    df_weather_in_cities = pd.json_normalize(d) 


    # filter the belgian cities
    df_cities_weather_in_be = df_weather_in_cities[df_weather_in_cities['city.country']=='BE']
```

## what are the dtypes of df_weather_in_cities?

```
id                            float64
city.name                      object
city.coord.lon                float64
city.coord.lat                float64
dtype: object
```

## the code #1, using .loc on the right side

```py
    df_cities_weather_in_be['lat_rounded'] = df_cities_weather_in_be.loc[:,('city.coord.lat')].apply(lambda x: np.round(x, 4))
```

## the code #2, using a simple column selection

```py
    df_cities_weather_in_be['long_rounded'] = df_cities_weather_in_be['city.coord.lat'].apply(lambda x: np.round(x, 4))
```

## the code #3, using .loc on the left side

```py
    df_cities_weather_in_be.loc[:,'long_rounded'] = df_cities_weather_in_be['city.coord.lat'].apply (lambda x: np.round(x, 4))
```

## the code #4, using .loc on the both sides

```py
    df_cities_weather_in_be.loc[:,'long_rounded'] = np.round(df_cities_weather_in_be.loc[:,'city.coord.lat'], 4)
```

## the error

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. 

Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy 

"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Comment: How is created `df_cities_weather_in_be` ?

Comment: @jezrael did you test my code? I have said that I have NOT found a solution to get rid the warning; the answer you are referring to proposes to disable the warning; I am looking for a solution not hiding the warning.

Comment: This errors is really unpleasant, becyse problem  is with `df_cities_weather_in_be`, how is created. So my comment was for ask code for create `df_cities_weather_in_be` for solution with copy for avoid warning

Comment: @jezrael df_cities_weather_in_be is created by reading a json file. I will update the question

Comment: Thanks, use `df_cities_weather_in_be = df_weather_in_cities[df_weather_in_cities['city.country']=='BE']. copy()` for avoid warning.

Comment: @jezrael, you are awesome! I do prefer when you answer to the question ;-) 

put your comment as an answer to vote for it!